# Why .net core web API receive corrupt data when publised on IIS but is OK with VS Studio+IIS express?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post, iis, asp.net-web-api

Sorry for this complicated title.

I did a very simple .net core web API (3.1).
This api is very simple, it waits for a POST request.
The API get body of the post request ( it's a XML, like a rest web service) and write this xml "stream" on the hard disk.

When i do test with runing the IIS Express service from Visual studio, i can push a lot of POST request : all my data are written on the disk.

I generate my application in release mode, then i publish my application on the IIS ( not standard IIS, the "IIS" buid in from Windows), then i do some post request.

The first or the second will be OK, but the third will result in a corrupted XML.
The File size is 100% what it should be, the file is containing some "NULLS" characters ( i can see them with notepad++).

I don't know if it's a bug in my code, or a problem in IIS. I rebooted IIS, i rebooted Windows, same issue.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
      .Build();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
           
            endpoints.MapPost("/", async context =>
            {
              
      
                var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.ContentLength)];
                var reader = await context.Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                string body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                
                System.IO.StreamWriter myWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\" + idUnique + ".xml", false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                myWriter.Write(body);
                myWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have difficulties to finds what is wrong. Size is exactly the same but 2/3 OK and 1/3 with "nulls".

Any ideas about this problem ?

I did all my test with SoapUI to push XML stream.

Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure to understand what do you mean

Comment: Your code seems to have a lot of faith in `context.Request.ContentLength` Have you verified its always correct ?

Comment: Is the file UTF16? Does it start with a byte order mark? (ie Is the problem that notepad is trying to read it as ascii?) Or, are you writing into the same file without truncating it?

Comment: Hi people, i modified the code using this for reading and it "appear" to solve my issue :     
`string body = await new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();`